# How can I enable login button of identity provider (external) on SP login page

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity server product version 5.0.0. I use SP1. In our latest architecture we use a specific login page for each service provider. Each service provider can be configured under different tenant domains, eventually with differences (for an example, for a tenant is configured the internal and the facebook login but for another tenant just the internal login).

I want to know if it is possible to visualize on the login page the external Identity provider login button according to the Service provider configuration under the specific tenant domain. Please help me to solve this, I am stuck on this advance configuration. I could not find any documents for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to my knowledge your requirement is possible with WSO2-IS.

Please refer document [1] for Customizing the login page for SAML SSO service providers.

And you can get more custom configuration details using this blog as well. [2]

Also if you need to re-theming wso2 management console, that also possible with WSO2-IS. Please find the reference document [3].

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Login+Pages
[2]http://dulanja.blogspot.com/2014/01/wso2-is-samlsso-customizing-login-page.html
[3]http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/12/retheming-carbon-products/